# draw circle on intersection of table cells HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to draw a circle on the intersections of html tables, but I am not sure how to get shapes into html tables. I want it to look like something just like picture below. I tried to use text and span, such as using border-radius to get the circle shape but I can't seem to figure out how to make it appear on the intersections.

[image: circle on intersection of tables]

Comment: Welcome to SO, I recommend checking out [mcve] as that will assist you in asking the question that will assist users in answering.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo-element like this:

```css
/* Basic styling for demo */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  position: relative;
}

/* Adds a red circle to the bottom-right of every cell */
td::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Adds a blue circle to the bottom-right of the cells in the first column */
td:first-child::after {
  background-color: blue;
}

/* Adds a green circle to the bottom-right of the cells in the last column */
td:last-child::after {
  background-color: green;
}

/* Adds a black circle to the bottom-right of the cells with the class "dot" */
td.dot::after {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="dot">3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This code will give you a small red circle on the bottom-right corner of every table cell. Starting with that, you can be more specific with what cell to add that circle using classes or [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).

EDIT:

Added other examples using pseudo-classes.

Also, to explain what's happening:

What does the trick is the `position: relative` in the `td` and the `position: absolute` in the `::after` pseudo-element.

This allows us to position the pseudo-element relative to its parent, the table cell. Meaning, if we use `right: 0`, our circle will be positioned starting on the right side of the table cell.

So, we set `right` and `bottom` to the negative half of the width/height of the circle (the radius) so its center point is positioned on the intersection.

Finally, border-radius gives us the round shape we want.

Answer (score 1):

You can create pseudo element to draw circle and position it within the table.

```css
td{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

/* Creating a pseudo element before the 3rd cell of the 2nd row */
tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3):before{
    content: '⚫';
    position: relative;
    top: -28px;
    left: -12px;
    /* You can use position relative and change the position of the element */
}
```

```html
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```